# How to draw a single contour line in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following code is borrowed from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Simplest default with labels')
```

The above code produces the contour plot with 7 contour lines. How to draw a single contour line say with the value `0.5`?

The output of the above code is:

[image]

Comment: try [`levels=1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR0RR.png) or [`levels=2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O9TS.png) , in `ax.contour`

Comment: or to get rid of contours where Z is less than 0, use `Z[Z<0] = np.nan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add contour value: CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, [0.5])

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, [0.5])
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So specify `levels`, like the comment says.

Comment: CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels = 1 ) ?

Comment: Yes, `ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[0.5])` (e.g. _`levels`: int or array-like, optional_)

Comment: I see, it could be added as a positional argument. But specifying levels = 2 just sets quantity of contours.

Comment: It was just an example, more to confirm that's what to OP was looking for

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney ok, got it